# Can't create a deferred then use it

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I have the following code (fiddle link at the bottom):

```
function def() {
    d = new $.Deferred;
    d.resolve();
    return d;}
a = def();
a.done(function(){
    console.log('test);
});
```

I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. It doesn't give me much in the way of clues about where the syntax error is, so I'm confused. As far as I can tell I've made function that returns a deferred then I've attached something to run after it using `.done`. Please help.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/y9x19h1h/1/)

Comment: You are missing a quote in your `console.log` statement.

Comment: You should get a line number in the error message. Build your test case in a standalone HTML document (so you don't suffer from the weirdness JSFiddle does to limit the damage third party scripts can do) so that line number is useful.

Comment: The error might not give you any clues, but syntax highlighting certainly should...

Answer (score 2):

You're just not closing the `"test"` string.

```
function def() {
    var d = new $.Deferred; // please, don't forget the var 
    d.resolve();
    return d
}
var a = def();
a.done(function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

Advice: Use an IDE for making this kind of mistake obvious, usually through colors. Even basic editors support syntax highlighting.

Comment: Or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.6.9.html)